# How to create a string of chars from a string using charAt and not using arrays?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to get a string of charAt values from an entered string without using arrays.
Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String [] args){

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   String str = "";  
   String encrypt = "";  
   int encry = 0;  
   int i = 0; 
   System.out.printf("Please enter a string: "); 
   str = input.nextLine();
   int length = str.length();
   System.out.println();
   while (length <= length-1)
      encry = str.charAt(++i);
      System.out.println(encry);
```

Comment: `length` will never be less than or equal to `length-1` ;-)

Comment: That makes sense. So other then the while condition does everything else look solid?

Answer (score 0):

while-condition should be something like `(i<liength)`

Block-brackets `{}` missing for the while.

Indexing starts with 0, thus it should be `str.charAt(i++);` instead of `str.charAt(++i);`.

Comment: Thank you that helped. Now to convert encry back to a string would it be a similar method?

Answer (score 0):

Using what you've already achieved, I made an encryption method. I've also added a decryption method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Please enter a string: ");
    String message = input.nextLine();
    String encryptedMessage = encrypt(message);
    System.out.println(encryptedMessage);
    System.out.println(decrypt(encryptedMessage));
    input.close();
}

public static String encrypt(String message) {
    String encrypted = "";
    int i = 0;
    int length = message.length();

    while (i < length) {
        int ascii = message.charAt(i++);
        encrypted += " " + ascii;
    }

    return encrypted.trim();
}

private static String decrypt(String encryptedMessage) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(encryptedMessage);
    String decryptedMessage = "";

    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        decryptedMessage += (char) scanner.nextInt();
    }

    scanner.close();

    return decryptedMessage;
}
```

**Challenge**

In the above code, the encrypted message has spaces in between each set of integers that represents a character. Taking one glance at the encrypted message, it's pretty easy to see that you just converted each character to its ASCII equivalent.

Instead of a space, try inserting a non-numerical character between the ASCII codes. Then, in the decryption method, use `Scanner#useDelimiter` to that character in order to retrieve the ASCII values.